# Twilio SMS auto response for Real Estate

Tags: sms, twilio

I'm trying to set up a "TEXT **CODE** to **NUMBER**" service through twilio. The code will vary from house to house but the number will stay the same (my twilio number)

I'm just wanting it to send a response with some text and a link.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to set this up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Thanks for checking out Twilio.  I'd suggest starting by working through our [Quickstarts](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart).  These will walk you through the basic concepts of working with Twilio and serve as a great foundation for you to start building your app.

If you don't to work through all of the quickstarts, I'd suggest at least checking out the [Replying to an incoming message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/sms/replying-to-sms-messages) quickstart, which seems like may address your specific scenario.

Hope that helps.